# Adding values to the edges of a network in R

Tags: r, igraph, ergm

I have a data set (csv file) of arms exports that consists of the following variables called `arms1993`:

`countryA`, `countryB`, `year of arms trade`, and the `value of the arms export from country A to B in each year`.

Here's some actual data from my data set:

| countryA | countryB | year | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Portugal | Angola | 1993 | 1 |
| Spain | Angola | 1993 | 17 |
| Germany | China | 1993 | 16 |
| France | China | 1993 | 166 |
| Germany | Croatia | 1993 | 0.5 |
| France | South Africa | 1993 | 20 |

I've created a network from this data set with the code below:

```
net_arms1993 <- as.network(arms1993, directed = TRUE)
net_arms1993
```

I can plot the network:

```
plot(net_arms1993)
```

What I'm having trouble doing is assigning the value of the arms export to each edge. My ultimate goal is to run a series of ERGMs using edge as a covariate in the model. What I can't figure out how to do is, how can I add this value? This is what I've come up with:

```
edge_values <- arms1993$TIV
set.edge.value(net_arms1993, "TIV", edge_values)
get.edge.value(net_arms1993, "TIV")
```

The `get.edge.value` function works (I retrieve the right values). However, I don't think it is working because when I plug it into the ERGM, it returns a value of `Inf` for the edge covariate:

```
arms.model1993 <- ergm(net_arms1993 ~ edges + edgecov(net_arms1993, "TIV"))
summary(arms.model1993)
```

Comment: It's hard to answer this without a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/r-language/articles/76995406/how-to-write-a-good-r-question-with-a-reproducible-example). If you include a short, sample dataset (not necessarily from your real data) and set out the packages you're using (`as.network()` exists in several packages), I suspect you'll get an answer pretty quickly.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Thank you, I did that and added a bit more to my query. Thanks for your help.